# IBM MQ XMS with .NET Core 3.1 - how fetch messages already existing on topic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ibm-mq, xms

Im trying to consume messages from WMQ from my .NET Core worker service. I get it to work if I start my service and then publish messages on queue, but my service ignores all already existing messages. I read about durable subscribers, but that does not seem to quite be what Im after.

currently using nuget : IBMXMSDotnetClient, 9.2.0.1

code:

```
var destinationName = _apexConsumerOptions.Destination;

var isTopic = destinationName.StartsWith("topic://");

destinationName = destinationName.Remove(0, 8);

_connectionWmq = CreateConnection();

_sessionWmq = _connectionWmq.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge);

_destination = isTopic ? _sessionWmq.CreateTopic(destinationName) : _sessionWmq.CreateQueue(destinationName);

_consumer = _sessionWmq.CreateConsumer(_destination);

_connectionWmq.Start();

while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    //  fetch message
    var message = _consumer.Receive(_apexConsumerOptions.Timeout);

    HandleMessage(message);
    await Task.Delay(_apexConsumerOptions.MillisecondsBetweenSyncPolls, stoppingToken);
}
_connectionWmq.Close();
```

I'm trying to subscribe to topic, not queue.

I also have issues with MessageListener only activating on first message posted, but that seems to be known issue with 9.2.

Comment: IBM MQ subscribers do not receive messages that were published prior to the subscription being created. The only exception is a retained pub/sub, but in this case it is only the most recent publish that is retained can be provided to the new subscriber. The difference between non-durable and durable is that you can resume a durable subscription and receive all of the messages that were published since the last time you were connected. If you want to be able to subscribe and get data from before you subscribe then you need to look at something like Kafka (IBM Event Streams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it was a durable subscriber I was after, so implementing that solved my issue.

link to docs @ ibm about durable subscribers : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/xms_csub_dur.htm

Comment: I went through the exact same process as you. The IBM MQ documentation is so bad- it's ridiculous that this key piece of information is buried.